# [Duntemann's Book 3rd Edition]. How could 16-bit 8086 address 16 times as much memory as 8080?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, memory-segmentation

Duntemann says **8086 could address 16 times as much memory as 8080** and has gone on to elaborate upon this as **16 * 64K = 1MB**. So I am assuming 16 bits at a time (16-bit processor) * 64K because 16 address lines (2^16). But, by that logic for calculation shouldn't 8080 (8-bit processor) also having 16 address lines have been able to address 8 * 64K = 0.5MB?

**shouldn't the 8086 then be able to address twice as much as 8080?**

[image: kindly note highlighted sentence]

Comment: 2^16 = 64K 16 address bits is 64Kbytes of address space.  8086 has segments so 4 more address bits 2^20 = 2^4 * 2^16 = 16 * 64K

Comment: are you saying the 8080 had segment registers as well?   the 8086 did and that made it 16 * 64K of address space.

Comment: that statement is correct the 8086 can address 16 times as much as the 8080 16 bits vs 20

Comment: 8 * 64K = 0.5megaBITS not bytes

Comment: if you want to count it that way then 8086 is 16 * 64K * 8 which is still 16 times the amount of the 8080

Answer (score 7, accepted):

16x is the difference between `2^20` and `2^16`.

The 8080 has 16 bits of address space, meaning it can access 2^16 (65,536) different addresses. The amount of memory it can access is therefore 65,536 * 
 (the amount of memory at each address). In our case, the amount of memory at each address is 1 byte, so the amount of addressable memory is 65,536 * 1 byte = 64KB.

The 8086 has 20 bits of address space, meaning it can access 2^20 different addresses (1MB)

And of course 1MB/64KB is 16.

Note that the "bit-ness" of a processor does not always reflect the size of its address bus. It often does, but not in these cases.

The 8080 is an 8-bit processor, but its address bus is 16 bits wide. Similarly the 8086 is a 16 bit processor but its address bus is 20 bits.

Comment: Thx. had a hunch this would be the answer after searching on Wikipedia. But was confused. Marking this as the better response (for me), considering I am a noob and this is the simpler answer.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Intel 8080](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8080)' Wikipedia page:

```
Address width   16-bit
```

From [8086](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086) page:

```
Address width   20 bits
```

4 more lines give 16x more address space.

To address the 1Mb of memory (20-bit) 8086 used [memory segmentation (real mode)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation#Real_mode), to get full memory address it used 2-bytes segment register and 2-bytes offset as:

```
segment * 16 + offset
```